# How can I sort file names by version numbers?

Tags: bash, sorting, shell, version

In the directory "data" are these files:

> command-1.9a-setup
>   command-2.0a-setup
>   command-2.0c-setup
>   command-2.0-setup

I would like to sort the files to get this result:

> command-1.9a-setup
>   command-2.0-setup
>   command-2.0a-setup
>   command-2.0c-setup

I tried this

```
find /data/ -name 'command-*-setup' | sort --version-sort --field-separator=- -k2
```

but the output was

> command-1.9a-setup
>   command-2.0a-setup
>   command-2.0c-setup
>   command-2.0-setup

The only way I found that gave me my desired output was

```
tree -v /data
```

How could I get with sort the output in the wanted order?

Comment: What locale are you using that sorts `c` before `a`?

Comment: Ups, there went something wrong with the copying.

Comment: Related for simple numbers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088370/how-to-sort-strings-that-contain-a-common-prefix-and-suffix-numerically-from-bas

Comment: @tripleee can we close the other way around, since this has much more views / votes? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Edit:** *It turns out that Benoit was sort of on the right track and Roland tipped the balance*

You simply need to tell `sort` to consider ***only*** field 2 (add ",2"):

```
find ... | sort --version-sort --field-separator=- --key=2,2
```

**Original Answer:** *ignore*

If none of your filenames contain spaces between the hyphens, you can try this:

```
find ... | sed 's/.*-\([^-]*\)-.*/\1 \0/;s/[^0-9] /.&/' | sort --version-sort --field-separator=- --key=2 | sed 's/[^ ]* //'
```

The first `sed` command makes the lines look like this (I added "10" to show that the sort is numeric):

```
1.9.a command-1.9a-setup
2.0.c command-2.0c-setup
2.0.a command-2.0a-setup
2.0 command-2.0-setup
10 command-10-setup
```

The extra dot makes the letter suffixed version number sort after the version number without the suffix. The second `sed` command removes the prefixed version number from each line.

There are lots of ways this can fail.

Comment: When I try only with this part I get the right order:   find /home/mm/ztest/ -name 'truecrypt-*-setup' | sed 's/.*-\([^-]*\)-.*/\1 \0/;s/[^0-9] /.&/'   But the whole row doesn't work;

Comment: @sid_com: Which fails for `command-10-setup`? They both work for me. What is your `locale`? What version of `sort` do you have?

Comment: With this sort-setup the command-10-setup is in the first output-row. locale: de_DE.UTF-8. sort (GNU coreutils) 7.1

Comment: @sid_com: When I set `LC_COLLATE=de_DE.utf8` and do the sort using GNU coreutils 7.4, `command-10-setup` is the last line (using `sort --version-sort --field-separator=- --key=2,2`).

Comment: The first line gives me the desired result. The second line (with sed) gives me the same result as a `sort --version-sort`.

Answer (score 30):

If you specify to sort that you only want to consider the second field (`-k2`) don't complain that it does not consider the third one.

In your case, run `sort --version-sort` without any other argument, maybe this will suit better.

Comment: It's not the third field (which is "setup" in every case).

Comment: Sorry, it *was* the third field, but it was the fact that it was *included* rather than *excluded*. You have to tell `sort` that the key starts *and stops* at field 2 using `-k2,2` to make the OP's command work.

Comment: `sort --version-sort` gives me this print-order: `command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-2.0-setup`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this works:

```
find /data/ -name 'command-*-setup' | sort -t - -V -k 2,2
```

not with sort but it works:

```
tree -ivL 1 /data/ | perl -nlE 'say if /\Acommand-[0-9][0-9a-z.]*-setup\z/'
```

-v:     sort the output by version
-i:     makes tree not print the indentation lines
-L level: max display depth of the directory tree

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: now it should work with `command-10.1-setup` too.

Comment: This also fails with non-GNU sort (i.e. in OS X or FreeBSD). This is a GNU solution, not a bash solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is to pad your numbers.

This example pads all numbers to 8 digits.
Then, it does a plain alphanumeric sort.
Then, it removes the pad.

```
$ pad() { perl -pe 's/(\d+)/0000000\1/g' | perl -pe 's/0*(\d{8})/\1/g'; }
$ unpad() { perl -pe 's/0*([1-9]\d*|0)/\1/g'; }
$ cat files | pad | sort | unpad
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-10.1-setup
```

To get some insight into how this works, let's look at the padded sorted result:

```
$ cat files | pad | sort
command-00000001.00000009a-setup
command-00000002.00000000-setup
command-00000002.00000000a-setup
command-00000002.00000000c-setup
command-00000010.00000001-setup
```

You'll see that with all the numbers nicely padded to 8 digits, the alphanumeric sort puts the filenames into their desired order.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat files
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-10.1-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0-setup

$ cat files | sort -t- -k2,2 -n
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-10.1-setup

$ tac files | sort -t- -k2,2 -n
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-10.1-setup
```

Comment: I don't get the same sorting with your sort-options.

Comment: What locale are you using? I don't get that order either.

Comment: I'm using `CYGWIN_NT-5.1 bacc 1.5.25(0.156/4/2) 2008-06-12 19:34 i686 Cygwin` and no special locale, so it should be the same as locale `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but... `ls -l --sort=version` may be of assistance (although for OP's example the sort is the same as done by `ls -l` in a RHEL 7.2):

```
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-2.0-setup
```

YMMV i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I have files in a folder and need to get those name in sort order, based on the number. E.g. -

```
abc_dr-1.txt
hg_io-5.txt
kls_er_we-3.txt
sd-4.txt
sl_rt_we_yh-2.txt
```

I need to sort them based on number.
So I used this to sort.

```
ls -1 | sort -t '-' -nk2
```

It gave me files in sort order based on number.

Answer (score 0):

version-sort can be quite easily implemented with jq:

```bash
$ ls -1 command-*-setup
command-1.9a-setup
command-10-setup
command-2.0-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
```

```
$ ls -1 command-*-setup | jq -Rnr '
#read input lines as an array
[inputs]
|sort_by(
    #extract version ("2.0a")
    split("-")[1]
    |[  #extract numbers
        (split("[a-z]";"")[0]|split(".")|map(tonumber)),
        #extract letter
        (split("[0-9]";"")[-1])
    ]
)
#extract values from array
|.[]'
command-1.9a-setup
command-2.0-setup
command-2.0a-setup
command-2.0c-setup
command-10-setup
```