# How to sort strings that contain a common prefix and suffix numerically from Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sorting

Here is a list of files:

```
some.string_100_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_101_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_102_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_23_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_24_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_25_with_numbers.in-it.txt
```

Now I would like to sort it numerically. Starting with *23* and ending with *102*.

I have tried `-n` and `-g`. `-t` does not help in these messy strings.

Can I ignore leading strings to the number with an option or do I have to be clever and script?

Comment: What do you want to do? and how are you going to use that sorted data?

Comment: It´s for a batch file so that I can throw files that are not too big to a program that processes one file at a time. I sorted it manually in the end but got curious so I posted the question here.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41655/how-to-sort-the-string-which-combined-with-string-numeric-using-bash-script | https://superuser.com/questions/79338/in-bash-how-to-sort-strings-with-numbers-in-them | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041210/how-can-i-sort-file-names-by-version-numbers

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `ls -lv`

From the man page:

```
-v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
```

Comment: Note that the `-v` option to `ls` is a GNU extension; since you're on Linux, that's OK, but it is not portable to other systems necessarily.

Comment: is there an analogous command with `find` instead of `ls` (or perhaps piping to `sort`)?

Comment: On Mac, can you can `brew install coreutils` and use `gls`.

Comment: [Don't use `ls` in scripts,](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) though.

Comment: @becko `find` always traverses the tree in a deterministic order and outputs the files in the order it finds them.

Comment: @becko sort has -V option which is "natural sort of (version) numbers within text"

Answer (score 43):

Try the following:

```
sort -t '_' -k 2n
```

- `-t '_'` (sets the delimiter to the underscore character)
- `-k 2n` (sorts by the second column using numeric ordering)

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/yS33h3)**.

Comment: Exactly! it was the `k` option that I had forgotten and was "hidden" in the man pages.

Answer (score 8):

If available, simply use `sort -V`. This is a sort for version numbers, but works well as a "natural sort" option.

```
$ ff=$( echo some.string_{100,101,102,23,24,25}_with_numbers.in-it.txt )
```

Without sort:

```
$ for f in $ff ; do echo $f ; done
some.string_100_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_101_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_102_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_23_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_24_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_25_with_numbers.in-it.txt
```

With sort -V:

```
$ for f in $ff ; do echo $f ; done | sort -V
some.string_23_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_24_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_25_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_100_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_101_with_numbers.in-it.txt
some.string_102_with_numbers.in-it.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

In the general case, try the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Briefly, break out the number into its own field, sort on that, and discard the added field.

```
# In many shells, use ctrl-v tab to insert a literal tab after the first \2
sed 's/^\([^0-9]*\)\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\2   \1\2/' file |
sort -n |
cut -f2-
```

This works nicely if the input doesn't have an obvious separator, like for the following input.

```
abc1
abc10
abc2
```

where you would like the sort to move the last line up right after the first.

Answer (score 1):

Not direct, but you can rename files moving the number part (with additional padded zeros as needed) as prefix.

Ex: 1.txt, 23.txt, 2.txt rename to
01.txt, 23.txt, 02.txt

now ls default output is numerical order
01.txt
02.txt
23.txt

A simple python script might help you. You can even use regex to do it in one shot, if you prefer.

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('*[0-9]*.py')
print(files)
import os
for f in files:
    # 64.smallest_word_window.py
    parts = f.split('_')
    number = str('%04d' % (int(parts[0])))+'_'
    del parts[0]
    new_parts = number + '_'.join( parts )
    print(f'{new_parts}')
    os.rename(f, new_parts)
```